# No instance(s) of type variable(s) T exists so that integer conforms to EventType<T>

Tags: java, lambda, event-handling, hamburger-menu, jfoenix

Im not super advanced at Java but im learning how to use the Lambda expresions. But i have an error in my code that i cant seem to fix by googling it. Can someone point me in the right direction.

```
@FXML
private JFXHamburger fxHamburger;

@FXML
private JFXDrawer fxDrawer;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
    HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition menuTask = new HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition(fxHamburger);
    menuTask.setRate(-1);
    fxHamburger.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (e) -> {
        menuTask.setRate(menuTask.getRate() * -1);
        menuTask.play();

        if (fxDrawer.isShown()) {
            fxDrawer.close();
        }else{
            fxDrawer.open();
        }
    });
}
```

[All the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1sFQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong `MouseEvent`. You should be using the [`javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) instead of [`java.awt.event.MouseEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) as you are using JavaFX.

Comment: I see no evidence that java.awt.event.MouseEvent is being used.

Comment: @VGR He posted an image.

Comment: So he did.  My mistake.

Comment: @VGR Not a problem. I probably should have avoided answering thinking of it to avoid encouraging posting images of code.